# How do I open only the clicked dropdown menu from a list of mulitple dropdown menus rendered with a while loop

Tags: javascript

I want to open only the clicked dropdown. I think there is a problem with updating the function or the ID for dropdown in a while loop.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <td>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">
      <img src="images/options.png" width="8" height="8" />
    </button>
  </td>
  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
  <td>
    <div
      id="myDropdown"
      class="dropdown-content"
      style="border-radius:15px;"
    ></div>
  </td>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```html
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var dropdown = document
      .getElementsByClassName('dropdowncontent')
      .classList.toggle('show');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementById()` returns a single element, not a list. Why are you looping over the results?

Comment: You also forgot the assignment: `var myDropDown = document.getElementById("myDropDown");`

Comment: Also, your `getElementById()` statement is useless since you're not assigning it to anything.  Incidentally, your browser will interpret your undeclared variable `myDropdown` as the element with that ID. But you should still explicitly declare it. Edit: Ha, @Barmar beat me to it.

Comment: Also, be aware that you cannot have more than one element with any given `id` value. That is why `document.getElementById` always only returns the first match. `id` duplication makes your HTML invalid, and couldn't be worse practice-wise.

Comment: so what correction should i make?

Comment: `myDropDown.classList.toggle("show")`

Comment: Fix what you received in the comments so far, adjust your question accordingly and then you can be helped.

Comment: I made a fix. please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit
>   Looks like you have edited your question and dropped finding by Id. You also have some inconsistency in the naming of your class in the markup `dropdown-content` vs `dropdowncontent` in the script.
>   I have updated my answer with the following assumptions.

- Since you said you are fetching `dropdowns` in a while loop, I assumed that there are multiple dropdowns with each having a toggle button to show or hide that particular dropdown's content. So I duplicated the markup to reflect that.
- With the button having an onClick function, there might be no need to `getElementsByClassName` but instead use the target button's parent and toggle it's class, then use `css` to show or hide the child content.

---

```js
function myFunction(thisButton){
  // Use the this context object to get the target/clicked button
  // Then find its parent
  var dropdownParent = thisButton.parentElement;
  
  // Toggle the class of that parent with a class that displays the content
  dropdownParent.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.dropdown-content {
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.show {
  background: #fef;
}
.dropdown.show .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <td>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">
      <img src="images/options.png" width="8" height="8" />
      Toggle Dropdown 1
    </button>
  </td>
  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
  <td>
    <div
      // You say you are returning multiple dropdowns, remove the id then
      id="myDropdown"
      class="dropdown-content"
      style="border-radius:15px;"
    >Dropdown 1 Content</div>
  </td>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <td>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">
      <img src="images/options.png" width="8" height="8" />
      Toggle Dropdown 2
    </button>
  </td>
  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
  <td>
    <div
      class="dropdown-content"
      style="border-radius:15px;"
    >Dropdown 2 Content</div>
  </td>
</div>
```

---

Note: The styles are irrelevant to the question, just some helpful visual representation. Hope this gives you an idea

Comment: this is fine but my point is I am fetching dropdowns from the database in a while loop. I need to open only the clicked dropdown.